# Dismiss modal and hiding modal by background click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need to add some code for dismissing modal by button and by clicking on body that got black background color.
How can I find this black area what is id or class name  [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqav0.png)

For button where I have `data-dismiss='modal'` I made in my js file on click on that button do something...
And that is to uncheck all checked radio buttons because if I close they will stay checked.
So I added this code on button on click

```
$(".close").click(function(){
    $('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', false);  
});
```

Now I need to find this black area under modal dialog and to say on click there do same but I looked up in console and I only saw it add something to body tag.

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: it is little hard but you can see on my website if you want ill give you some email and pass for demo

Comment: can you try this code window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

Comment: Chrome [web tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/?hl=en) can help you to find the id of the dark background. The put a `click` listener of that element to close the modal.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.close').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('#Model').hide()
});
```

Comment: when you click the close button with class 'close', It will hide the model contains this close button.